# nginx docker container won't start at boot

Tags: docker, nginx

I have an `nginx` Docker container which runs fine from the command line but which does not restart at boot.   It is started with `--restart=on-failure` which I understand *should* also start it at boot (it certainly works that way on my other Docker containers).

```
docker run --name nginx  --restart=on-failure --detach --mount type=bind,source=/etc/ssl,target=/etc/ssl,readonly --mount type=bind,source=/etc/pki,target=/etc/pki,readonly --mount type=bind,source=/etc/letsencrypt,target=/etc/letsencrypt,readonly -p 443:443 -d nginx
```

Any ideas why this might be the case or how I find out what's upsetting it?  `docker logs nginx` gives me nothing, just the log up to the end of the shut-down of the machine.  This is on Centos 8 and, in case it matters, the `nginx` configuration file contains:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  myurl.net;

    ssl_certificate        /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.net/privkey.pem;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my_ca.crt;
    ssl_crl                /etc/ssl/CA/ca.crl;
    ssl_verify_client on;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8080/;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

...where the `location` line is on a local docker network that lets `nginx` talk with another docker container that runs the HTTP server which ultimately does the serving (`nginx` is just in the loop to perform client authentication via SSL).  Could this network bit somehow be causing a problem?

Comment: If `--restart=on-failure` didn't restart it when it quit, it didn't fail, it just quit. Try `--restart=always`

Comment: Aha!  Well done, I guess the other containers I have don't exit cleanly while `nginx` does and hence I thought that `--restart=on-failure` did the trick.  Confirmed that `--restart=always` solves my problem, many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart Docker Containers when they Crash Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109247/restart-docker-containers-when-they-crash-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

As @triplee points out, `--restart=on-failure` *doesn't* actually start the Docker container when the machine is rebooted, it only *appears* to do this in some cases if the Docker image in question doesn't exit gracefully at system shutdown: the image appears to fail and hence Docker will restart it when the machine comes back up.

The correct directive to ensure that a well-behaved Docker image, one which exits gracefully like the `nginx` one and hence doesn't raise an error, is to use `--restart=always`.